# Is it acceptable to use multiple inheritance in domain model?

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design

In modeling business domain many times I came across a situation where multiple inheritance of a class could make my model a lot cleaner and simple. I know, in most of the programming languages, including java that is going to be the prime language of my project,  multiple inheritance is not supported. But it could be implemented through interfaces.
Is it a good or at least acceptable idea to use multiple inheritance to model domain in UML to explain the concepts and leave it on implementers how they implement it? Or it has more cons than pros?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. It's possible that one concept plays multiple roles; a la `IMakeCoffee` and `IDrinkCoffee`.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is acceptable. Only thing is, most of the times when you think it is it really isn't. To find a proper use-case for multiple inheritance is rare. What is yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it a good or at least acceptable idea to use multiple inheritance to model domain in UML to explain the concepts and leave it on implementers how they implement it?*

On the one hand, if you are going to do UML modeling (which should represent real code) and talk software engineering concepts like multiple inheritance, make sure that it fits the programming language, which is the language of the programmer. On the other hand if you are trying to convey high level concepts you can completely leave the term multiple inheritance out of it and draw non-UML diagrams any which way you want. My advise would be to complete separate the conceptual from the implementation specifics, because in my experience this will inevitably lead to confusion. Try to translate between the two, but don't mix.

Furthermore, you will not be loved by your team when you saddle them with the fact that the programming language they work with doesn't support multiple inheritance. Simply work with them at finding a proper functioning solution. You may have to compromise, but such is life.

Mulitple inheritance is not inherently bad. Coming from a C++ background, but working a lot with Java nowadays occasionally I wished Java would support multiple inheritance. But those occasions are very rare, and that's why you should be careful to think that multiple inheritance is the only proper way to achieve your goal.